# How to fix CardView's padding for APIs older than android L

Tags: android

I'm trying to use card view to create shadow effect for a rounded rect button in my app. It works fine on Android L, but not fine on the older APIs. My xml code is:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="6dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:contentPadding="0dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white_color"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/view_prepared_trip"
            android:background="@drawable/view_prepared_trip_button_bg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="30dp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The result when run this code is shown in picture in the following link. The pickture on left hand is showing the result on Android L, which is ok. And the picture on right hand is showing the result on older APIs, which is not good.

http://www.mediafire.com/view/v6keegfec3l1656/Capture.JPG

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Consider setting [cardPreventCornerOverlap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#attr_android.support.v7.cardview:cardPreventCornerOverlap) to false on your CardView.